# Azure DevOps Service connection - How to get IP for WhiteListing

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory, serviceconnection

The service (Jfrog Artifactory) being used utilizes a whitelist of authorized IPs. How can I determine the IP(s) that the ADO service will be using to so that I can add them to the whitelist?

Tried creating the service connection - verify fails

Answer (score 2):

> How can I determine the IP(s) that the ADO service will be using to so that I can add them to the whitelist?

To get the Azure DevOps Service IP to add to whitelist to create service connection, you can follow the steps:

Step1: Navigate to **Organization Settings -> Overview** and check the Organization region.

Step2: Check this doc: [Inbound connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#inbound-connections). Find the IP ranges of your region and add to whitelist.

```
Region      IP V4 ranges
Australia East  20.37.194.0/24
Australia South East    20.42.226.0/24
Brazil South    191.235.226.0/24
Central Canada  52.228.82.0/24
Asia Pacific (Singapore)    20.195.68.0/24
South India 20.41.194.0/24
Central United States   20.37.158.0/23
West Central United States  52.150.138.0/24
East United States  20.42.5.0/24
East 2 United States    20.41.6.0/23
North United States 40.80.187.0/24
South United States 40.119.10.0/24
West United States  40.82.252.0/24
West 2 United States    20.42.134.0/23
Western Europe  40.74.28.0/23
United Kingdom South    51.104.26.0/24
```